# How to postback to a controller function when a value is selected from dropdown

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have created a dropdownlist on the view and showing a list.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedId, new SelectList(Model.List, "ID", "Name"))
```

I want to refresh the page when the user selects the value from the drop down.
I don't know how to map the selection event from dropdown to a controller function without clicking any button.

On the view load there is a controller function which is populating the view with the list.

```
public ActionResult Populate()
{
  List<string> list = get it from sql server
  ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
  viewModel.list = list;
   return view();
}
```

But how do you call a controller function which will take the selected value as an Id and retrieves the data and refreshes the page with the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your layout in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select:[autopostback=true],input[type=checkbox]:[autopostback=true],input[type=radio]:[autopostback=true]').live('change',function () {
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

in your view:

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedId, new SelectList(Model.List, "ID", "Name"), new { autopostback = "true" })
}
```

The form that your dropdownlist is in will get submitted when you change selection of your dropdownlist. If the result of the action of that form is the same page, it will be reloaded with whatever stuff being updated

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it without javascript help. Just bind on select event and send the form or make an ajax request.

using jQuery:

```
$('#yourDropDownId').change(function(){
    $('#yourFormId').submit();
});
```

or if you need ajax call insted of submit use [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Comment: Can you share an example... or blog post related to that please?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#ddl").change(function() {
       var strSelected = "";
       $("#ddl option:selected").each(function() {
           strSelected += $(this)[0].value;
       });
       var url = "/Home/MyAction/" + strSelected;

       $.post(url, function(data) {
           // do something if necessary
       });
   });
});
```

or

```
<%=Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedId, new SelectList(Model.List, "ID", "Name"), new { onchange="this.form.submit();" })%>
```

Comment: This method would probably be easy to add ajax behavior to later if you decide to enhance the functionality later.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. In your javascript you have:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#SelectedId').change(function () {
                var id = $(this).val();
                $.getJSON("/YourController/YourAction", { id: id},
                function (data) {               
                    $("#SomeDivSelector").html(data);
                });
            });

        });
```

Your controller should look like:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult YourAction(int id)
{
  //do something
  return Json(ControlToString("~/Views/YourController/YourView.cshtml", yourModelWithData), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And ControlToString is defined:

```
 private string ControlToString(string controlPath, object model)
        {
            //CshtmlView control = new CshtmlView(controlPath);
            RazorView control = new RazorView(this.ControllerContext, controlPath, null, false, null);

            this.ViewData.Model = model;

            using (System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter()))
            {
                control.Render(new ViewContext(this.ControllerContext, control, this.ViewData, this.TempData, writer), writer);

                string value = ((System.IO.StringWriter)writer.InnerWriter).ToString();
                return value;
            }
        }
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to apply, against the concept of the technology you're using.
MVC based on ASP.NET technology, but another way executing. MVC not use better of life cycle of ASP.NET, so, does not "Postback". MVC - in the root based on architectural pattern, that allows to separate the different layers of any system, therefore approach to the development on current technology is completely different.  learn more about MVC: http://www.asp.net/mvc

if you want still implement your problem you can use ASP.NET concept and use AutoPostback property of DropDownList control.